# Upload a picture using ASP.NET MVC4 RAZOR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, razor

I am using kendo mobile to build a mobile application in which the user will be able to click and upload a photo.  When they first enter the page, it will show their current photo, I want to be able to click and open file explorer on their device and have the ability to show a preview of their photo in place of the old one. Then when the click done it will send it to my MVC controller where I can then send it to where I want.  I cant figure out how to send my file to the controller.

HTML

```
<div id="NewAccountUploadContainer">
<img id="NewAccountUpload" src="~/Images/btnCamera.png" data-bind="click: uploadPhoto" />
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendNewPhoto", "MobilePlatform", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input id="ImageUploadBtn" style="display: none" type="file" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" style="display: none" />
}
<div id="ImgUploadTxt" data-bind="click: uploadPhoto">
    Upload a<br />
    different photo.
</div>
```

The #ImageUploadBtn will be triggered by the #NewAccountUpload or #ImgUploadTxt clicks in jquery which works, but I cant get it to display a file or send to my controller when I trigger the submit.

C# Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendNewPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The file is always null at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the Kendo for mvc4, and a mobile implementation, and I'm using the follow code, works for me:

View:
    
        
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .Name("files")
            )

Controller

```
public ActionResult Submit(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            if (files != null)
            {
                TempData["UploadedFiles"] = GetFileInfo(files);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Result");
        }

        public ActionResult Result()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetFileInfo(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            return
                from a in files
                where a != null
                select string.Format("{0} ({1} bytes)", Path.GetFileName(a.FileName), a.ContentLength);
        }
```